# autoreleasepool for nested methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

Say I have following code:

```
- (void) abc
{
   @autoreleasepool
   {
      NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ABC %d", 12];
      [self pqr];
   }
}

- (void) pqr
{
   NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PQR %d", 14];
}
```

For the above code, after the execution of method `abc`, will only `str` be released or `str2` will also be released?

Answer (score 1):

**Both**. If you are not sure, create your custom class and override dealloc implementation and add there some log message to not only believe me but experienced it on your own.